# How do I use a variable within a variable in PHP?

Tags: php

When I use

`echo $stores_open_starts["tuesday"];`
or
`echo $stores_open_starts['tuesday'];`

I get

`11.00`

Now, I want to use this dynamically. I generate the day like this:

`$today_date = date('d', strtotime("today"));
$today_date = strtolower($today_date);`

But then when I do

`echo $stores_open_starts["{$today_date}"];`
or
`echo $stores_open_starts[$today_date];`

it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$stores_open_starts["{$today_date}"]` means that you want to print an array element with index equals to `$today_date` value. did your array contains that index?

Comment: @developer Yes, it contains every day. monday to sunday.

Comment: Have you tried `echo($today_date);` to check it's the value you expected?

Comment: Uh oh...I think I found the problem. Doh!

Comment: if you want to use full textual representation of the day of the week  you should use `l` (lower case L) instead of `d`

Comment: `$today_date`  in your code will equal day number not name

Comment: Also, don't forget to lowercase your response as `date('l')` will return `Tuesday` and it appears you want `tuesday`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want the full day of the week as a string. That's:

```
$today_date = date('l', strtotime("today"));    //You should use 'l' and not 'd'
$today_date = strtolower($today_date);
```

`'d'` returns the day of the month, not the name of the weekday.